# converting curl to wget

Tags: curl, wget

I have these two commands that I am trying to convert from `curl` to `wget`.

```
location=$(curl -Is "https://github.com/some/release"| grep "Location")
curl -Lo /usr/bin/somerelease "${some_release_url}"
```

How can I achieve this?

For the first, I've tried

```
wget -q --spider "https://github.com/some/release"
```

but the value of `location` is nil. 
For the second, I've tried

```
wget -ro /usr/bin/somerelease "${some_release_url}"
```

but that gives me a flag not found.

Works as expected with `curl` but I can't configure the correct `wget` flags for this to work. I used [this](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/wget.htm) as a reference.

Comment: this isn't about programming, take it to [superuser.com](https://superuser.com) where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this site [curlconverter](https://curlconverter.com/wget/).